# How to destroy a window placed in the heap correctly?

Tags: c++, window, wtl

I have a legacy code. The code works like this: after an `Event1` has happened it creates an window object ( inherited from `CWindowImpl` class ) in the heap. After an `Event2` has happened it applies changes made in the window, closes it by calling `DestroyWindow()` and frees the memory in the heap by calling `delete`.

This code is buggy because it deletes the window object before all the messages for this window are processed. How to know for sure when it's safe to call `delete` for the window object?

The only solution i found out is to override `OnFinalMessage` and call `delete this` there. I don't like it because it must be guaranteed that the object is created in the heap only. Are there better ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Having done `DestroyWindow`, you have the handle of the window destroyed, so it is safe to use `delete` on the window class pointer. No late messages can arrive at that point.

`OnFinalMessage` comes from inner WTL's handler for `WM_NCDESTROY` message.